# Feature Activation

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007, moss, stsadm

We want to activate the existing future for more than 100+ site-collections, what would be the right choice? can we achieve this through Powershell?

Comment: The future will be actived automatically! Do not try to intervene, or Skynet will send Arnold after you!

Comment: actually, we have deployed a solution package and which installs few features however they are not activated automatically, we have to activate the feature manually. I do not want to activate the feature manually so looking for some help to activate them thru script.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to code yourself, you can always download the [SharePoint Feature Admin Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.com.
It will allow you to select a Web Feature and activate/deactivate in recursively on a Site Collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes powershell would make this easy.

But there is also the stsadm command "activatefeature".
Together with the stsadm command "enumsites" and a bit of creating command script building you should go a long way.